# Zend Joining multiple tables with rows containing rows

Tags: sql, zend-framework, join

I have two tables: owner, books, and authors. Each owner has many books, and each book has one or many authors. I want to run one query, giving it the owner's id, and get the list of all the books and authors back. I am hoping that the returned object has something like

```
 $obj->first_name
 $obj->last_name
 $obj->books
```

And then $obj->books itself has

```
 $obj->books->title
 $obj->books->authors
```

And then $obj->books->authors has its own name and first name.

Can someone please direct me towards a tutorial for this? I know I need to use join, but when using it, I end up getting everything squeezed into one object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining of tables in Zend framework2 is like as Zend framework version 1+  , But in Zendframework 2 we can use TableGateway to manipulate with tables. I hope the following code will help to you.

```
   $select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();

   $select->join('joining_tbl_name', 'tbl_name_belongs_to_this_model.book_id = joining_tbl_name.book_id', array('*'), 'joining_type');

   $select->where(array('tbl_name_belongs_to_this_model.owners_id' => {owner_id_value}));

   $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);   

   return $resultSet;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If this answer is working fine, then kindly do up vote for me.